# Make Eclipse RCP Intro part of a perspective

Tags: eclipse, rcp, universal, perspectives

For a product we are creating, we want to be able to have the welcome screen display in a perspective (which we are calling "Start Here"). The intro is the only thing that needs to be in that perspective, however, when I try to add our intro view to the perspective, it says that the view already exists in the layout.

I have tried programmatically closing the intro, messing around with standby mode etc but I cant get it working.

The intro is an XHTML one and we use internal Eclipse "action links" (e.g. http://org.eclipse...?runAction etc) extensively (hence the reason that we need to use the intro framework.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I could get it added to a perspective, or at the very least get the intro fully maximised when you select a specific perspective (using the "showIntro" method results in it displaying oddly, bunched to one side).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Intro view is a sticky view, so its placeholder is created by default to every perspective, to the right of editor area. There's no public API to remove a placeholder once it is created and when you try to create one you get the error that it already exists.

You can maximize Intro view like this:

```
IWorkbenchPage page =
    PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
page.setPartState(page.findViewReference("org.eclipse.ui.internal.introview"),
    IWorkbenchPage.STATE_MAXIMIZED);
```

This should probably be done in [`IPerspectiveListener`](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IPerspectiveListener.html).perspectiveChanged() rather than in perspective factory.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the view to the perspective, call IIntroManager.showIntro() or WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.openIntro()