# Eclipse rcp : How can the welcome page appear full screen everytime?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I want to fixed the workbench and appear the weclome page everytime full screen.

But when I call the method `layout.setfixed(true)` in the Class Perspective the welcom page can't be full screen.

Comment: Welcome page is not part of the perspective. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7646344/150166

Answer (score 2):

To open in full screen, following code in `postWindowOpen()` method of `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor` class can be used

```
getWindowConfigurer().getWindow().getShell().setMaximized( true );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in the preWindowOpen-method of the WorkbenchWindowAdvisor:

```
 public class ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor extends WorkbenchWindowAdvisor {
     ...
     public void preWindowOpen() {
        ...
        PlatformUI.getPreferenceStore()
              .setValue(IWorkbenchPreferenceConstants.SHOW_INTRO, true);
     }
```

This will show the welcome page everytime in full screen size when the application is started.

Comment: Yes I tried it in a project and it works quite fine. Do you have configured the extension points "org.eclipse.ui.intro" and "org.eclipse.ui.intro.config"?